Laptop changed to Kubuntu--need ethernet adapter for Kubuntu
My laptop was Win 11, using ethernet adapter to usb, now changed to Kubuntu 23 and adapter is obsolete; but i cannot find an ethernet adapter to usb port that will work with Kubuntu. Does anyone know a brand name for one? It must come with Kubuntu drivers. This is probably a common problem.
